# mousemove keeps executing

Tags: jquery, mousemove, mousedown

I'm trying to click in a div and drag while clicking to perform a "select" in jQuery and the mousemove keeps running. I've tried:

```
var draggin = false;

 $(where)
        .mousemove(function(event){
                if(draggin == false) return;
...
```

tried

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

and:

```
$("body").off("mousemove");
```

and:

```
 $(document).mouseup(function() {
            $(document).off("mousemove mousedown");
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you attach the mouse event(s)?

Comment: i'm just attaching to the DOM element it's the div so the div has mousedown mousemove and mouseup each seperated not binded

Comment: So you need to remove it from the element it was attached to

Answer (score 0):

I suppose "where" is your element.

Try using:

```
$(where).off("mousemove");
```